# Prevent Back Login After Logout by hitting the Back button on Browser in L5?

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5

My problem is I want to do when I already logout, If I click back button on browser it never back admin home page.

Now when I click back button It show admin secret pages, But when I refresh the page then It back to login page.

I solved it write the code in filter.php on Laravel 4.2

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
 $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
$response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
$response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
});
```

But Now how can I do Prevent Back Login After Logout by hitting the Back button on Browser in L5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep this line in top of the login page.That will clear cache and prevent back page(pabel)

```
<?php echo
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: text/html');?>
```

Comment: Works very well. Thank You

Answer (score 4):

that work for me:

Put this javascript code at the end of your login page, with this you can not go back and then once outside the system can not reach the previous pages

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
            history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
            window.onpopstate = function () {
                history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            };
        } else {
            var ignoreHashChange = true;
            window.onhashchange = function () {
                if (!ignoreHashChange) {
                    ignoreHashChange = true;
                    window.location.hash = Math.random();
                } else {
                    ignoreHashChange = false;   
                }
            };
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.

Comment: You have to be in context to understand the code that place worked for me , and put my source , so do not understand what the problem is ... it's just copy and paste the code ...

Comment: StackOverflow it's not just about copy+paste the code that people give to you when answering the question, it's also (and mostly) about learning how to do stuff that you didn't knew before. This is what makes us better, understanding what the problem is and how the given answer(s) solve it. Anyhow I see you added some details, that's one step forward.

Comment: I just want to help dude, let's the people decide if is wrong or not :-) have a nice day Cristik!

Comment: I also tried to help you improve your answer, a detailed answer is likely to get more votes than a code-only one. You too have a nice day.

Comment: No point to fume people. It works. And there is really no need to explain that code. If someone knows JS, he understands. If someone is not familiar (enough) with JS then, then I do not see any easy way to crash-course him/her.

Comment: And this solution seems to be the only one, given that Chrome (and its brethren) clearly ignore accepted answer here. Very strange policy, these days, when sensitive data is under siege left and right. 'Do no evil' right Google?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
            history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
            window.onpopstate = function () {
                history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            };
        } else {
            var ignoreHashChange = true;
            window.onhashchange = function () {
                if (!ignoreHashChange) {
                    ignoreHashChange = true;
                    window.location.hash = Math.random();
                } else {
                    ignoreHashChange = false;   
                }
            };
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).